# How to show that a given linear program is feasible?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \frac{1}{2} x_1 + x_2\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 12\\ & x_1 \leq 4\\ & x_1, x_2 \geq 0\end{array}$$

I know the definition for it to be inconsistent is

$$(Ax \leq b) \vdash (0^{T}x \leq -1)$$

It's consistent otherwise. But I don't see how to apply the definition to the pratical problem.

Comment: That's an interesting definition, I thought one would call it consistent if there are feasible points (and one example is sufficient to prove consistency), and inconsistent otherwise. I think both definitions are equivalent, though.

Comment: How are they equivalent? What does |- mean?

Comment: Well, the second question is for OP. The first: I _think_ it means that you can derive the latter from the former in some way (speculation: there is a $y$ with non-negative components with $y^TA=0^T$ and $y^Tb=-1$). That's clearly impossible if there is a feasible point, and the other direction would follow with Alternative Farkas’ Lemma, say.

Comment: You can use the Big-M method to determine the feasibility of a linear programming problem.

Comment: This LP is feasible and its feasibility set is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBjra.png). However, the inequality $0^\top x = 0 \leq -1$ will *always* be infeasible (and I can't see how this relates to feasibility). What is the meaning of $\vdash$?